# will git pull auto merge if pulled from _any_ remote?

Tags: git, git-merge

let's say I have the following config file

```
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[remote "origin"]
    url = ssh://origin.com
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[remote "faraway"]
    url = ssh://faraway.com
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/faraway/*
```

if I do `git checkout master; git pull origin` then:

- `fetch` will run
- `merge` will merge the fetched branch with my current branch.

If I run `git checkout master; git pull faraway`, then will `git-merge` merge anything? After all, I am pulling from a different remote than the configured remote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `remote = origin` specifies the default behavior for pull (fetch actually) when you are in the branch. So when you do `git pull` , the remote is origin ( which is also the default i.e even if the remote was not specified, it would have pulled from origin. If some other remote was specified, that remote would have been fetched.)

And when you do `git pull faraway`, it will fetch the faraway branches but will not merge ( as faraway is not the configured remote) it in the current branch master, unless you do `git pull faraway master`

Comment: when I tried only specifying a non-default remote (and no branch) I got this: `You asked to pull from the remote 'production', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.`

Comment: @Thr4wn - Yeah, isn't that what I am saying? You have to do `git pull faraway master`

Comment: well, I feel dumb now ;P that is exactly what you said.

Answer (score 0):

`git pull non-default-remote` will return

```
You asked to pull from the remote 'production', but did not specify
a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote
for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.
```

But if I type

```
git pull non-default-remote `git config remote.non-default-remote.fetch`
```

then it will automatically merge with whatever is currently checked out on the remote and **completely ignore** the default merge option since I'm pulling from a non-default remote.